# Convert field from list of objectids to list of string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, tostring

I have this pipeline:

```
[
            {"$lookup": {
                "from": "base_model",
                "localField": "suboptions",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "suboptions"
            }},
            {"$project": {"name": "$name",
                          "uuid": "$uuid",
                          "is_required": "$is_required",
                          "is_suboption": "$is_subption",
                          "suboptions": "$suboptions",
                          "option_uuid": "$option_uuid",
                          "is_in_stock": "$is_in_stock",
                          "created_at": "$created_at",
                          "updated_at": "$updated_at",
                          "_id": 0,
                          }},
            {"$addFields": {
                "suboptions.id": {"$toString": "$suboptions._id"}
            }},
            {"$project": {
                "suboptions._id": 0,
            }}

        ]
```

If I remove the $addFields stage it works fine, but I need to get the result in JSON serializable format, so I need to change the type of _id field in suboptions to string, but this is returning **Unsupported conversion from array to string in $convert with no onError value.**
How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use `$map` aggregation array operator to convert the array field of objects to an array field of strings.

Comment: I want to change every _id from ObjectID to string id, *$map* is returning the list of all ids in every id field in suboptions

Comment: You can update your post with a sample array before and after conversion - it will be useful for someone writing (or suggesting) a solution.

Comment: You should use $map to apply $toString to each of the _ids

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$addFields` stage likewise made it work:

```
{
        "$addFields": {
            "suboptions": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$suboptions",
                    "in": {
                        "id": {"$toString": "$$this._id"},
                        "admin_uuid": "$$this.admin_uuid",
                        "description": "$$this.description",
                        "price": "$$this.price",
                        "option_uuid": "$$this.option_uuid",
                        "created_at": "$$this.created_at",
                        "updated_at": "$$this.updated_at",

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```